# ActiveMQ 5.5.1 broker did not start in linux

Tags: jms, activemq-classic

i downloaded latest activemq 5.5.1 version and try to run it in Linux or Saloris, both failed with below messsage

./activemq start

INFO: Loading '/myhome/.activemqrc'
INFO: Using java '/myjdk/jdk-1.6.0-25-64/bin/java'
INFO: Starting - inspect logfiles specified in logging.properties and log4j.properties to get details
INFO: pidfile created : '/myhome/activemq_5_5_1/apache-activemq-5.5.1/data/activemq.pid' (pid '16067')

the same thing happens if I use commands like below
./activemq start xbean:file:/myhome/activemq_5_5_1/apache-activemq-5.5.1/conf/activemq.xml

Linux info:
OS:
 2.6.18-194.26.1.el5 #1 SMP Fri Oct 29 14:21:16 EDT 2010 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
JDK:
java version "1.6.0_25"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_25-b06)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.0-b11, mixed mode)

Unix info:
SunOS 5.10
JDK:
java version "1.6.0_17"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_17-b04)
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 14.3-b01, mixed mode)

Comment: I removed the service-broker tag, it's specific to an MS SQL-Server feature.

Comment: wow, thx a lot. I was not aware of that

Answer (score 2):

It looks as though its starting.  Have you tried to check the status of the pid?  You can also run it as ./activemq console and it will run in the forground as apposed to the background which is what ./activemq start does.  You should also check the logfile to see what errors if any are present.

Comment: well, the process is started, but i did not see the broker started successfully. there's no errors in the log, while  i did not see such messages in the log as expected; INFO  ActiveMQ JMS Message Broker (ID:apple-s-Computer.local-51222-1140729837569-0:0) has started;